# How can we view the image of curvature form under invariant polynomial of degree $k$ $f(\Omega)$ as a 2$k$-form?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, characteristic-classes

I'm currently studying from the book of Loring Tu, 'Differential Geometry: Connections, Curvature and Characteristic classes'. chapter 23 sector 2.

what confused me is that I can only view $P(\Omega)$ as a globally defined real-valued function on $M$, how can I view $P(\Omega)$ as a $2k$-form?

Comment: $\Omega$ is a tensorial 2-form on the principal bundle. How do you obtain a real-valued function?

Comment: Brief example: the trace operator is a symmetric polynomial  (of degree 1) on the vector space $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{C})$. Then $\text{trace}(\Omega)$ gives a 2-form on the base space, because it is still tensorial and is furthermore adjoint-invariant.

Comment: A more involved example would be $P(A)=\text{trace}(A^2) - \text{trace}(A)^2$. Here the powers on the space $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{C})$ are to be mapped via the Chern-Weil homomorphism to wedge products of the curvature.

Comment: yeah, i thought $\Omega$ has been viewed as an element of $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{C})
$ on a chart and $P$ maps $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{C})
$ into $\mathbb{C}$, so $P(\Omega)$ is a globally defined complex-valued function, i still cant get what you mean that $tr(\Omega)$ is a $2$-form

Comment: $\Omega$ is not an element of $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{C})$, but a 2-form with values in said Lie algebra. That means, evaluated in a point $p$ and on two tangent vectors $v_1,v_2\in T_p(...)$, you have indeed $\Omega_p(v_1,v_2)\in \mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{C})$. Now you can compose that 2-form with the trace, then $\text{tr}\big(\Omega_p(v_1,v_2)\big)\in \mathbb{C}$, and you explain the 2-form $\text{tr}\Omega$ by this formula pointwise.

Comment: hereby $(...)$ depends on the context as there is not $the$ $one$ notion of curvature.

Comment: i see. but there is still one problem left, what does $P(\Omega)(v_1,⋯,v_{2k})$ look like when $k>1$? and how does it preserve anti-symmetric?

Comment: I suggest you write out explicit formulas for $P(\Omega)$, things like $\sum \epsilon_{ij}^{k\ell} \Omega_{ik}\wedge\Omega_{j\ell}$.

Comment: If you look up the Chern-Weil homomorphism mentioned in a former comment you will notice how the multiplication of polynomials is mapped to the wedge of forms, preserving anti-symmetry. How this wedge product precisely looks like depends on the context in which you want to study the curvature forms and polynomials of it. Note that $P(\Omega)$ is merely a $2k$-form if $P$ is a homogeneous polynomial of order $k$, otherwise it will be a linear combination of $2k$-forms with different $k$'s.